# How to organize this: traders have fruits and recipes too

Tags: 7, nodes, commerce

I'm building a site in D7 for a little community garden mall with 30 traders/shops. There is a trader which sells fruits, another one sells cakes, another one sells dairy products, and so on.

And I have a page with lots of recipes. The recipes should link to the traders. So for Spaghetti Aglio e Olio: The spaghetti you buy at the wheet farmer, the garlic at the vegetable farmer and a white wine at the liquor shop.

I have a content type trader. And a content type recipe.

How do I organize the products? 
We even think about selling some of the products online one day. So that a site visitor could order a box of vegetables of a trader.

Thanks, Joerg

Answer (score 2):

I would look into using the [references module](http://drupal.org/project/references), you can reference one content type from another, for example on a ingredient page such as white wine, you could reference Spaghetti Aglio as a "you can make this from this ingredient".

Then on a traders content type you can refer to the ingredients etc

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is using taxonomy and views. That way you can have an ingredients taxonomy which you can then add the terms to both the trader and the recipe. To get the recipes to show up on the traders and the traders to show up on the recipes you can then use views contextual filters and relations in conjunction with display suite or panels. I would do it this way because this would allow you to add images, descriptions and many more connections between the actual ingredients and display them easily using one of the many views display plugins.